# The sum of a column using macro Excel 2010 vba

Tags: excel, vba

I use this macro for calculating the sum but it doesn't work. This is what I tried so far:

```
Sub sum()

I = .Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row

cumul = 0
For E = 2 To I
 cumul = cumul + Cells(E, 2)
Next
Range("E7") = cumul

End Sub
```

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Comment: Do you want to find the Sum for Column E  (looking for last row using `I = .Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row`) or Column B (`cumul = cumul + Cells(E, 2)`) ?

Comment: hey,My tab like that Name tab E1: production,E2 :56, E3: 67, E4: 67 etc... and i want the sum for all this columns

Comment: So you want to sum all values in Column E (until last row with data) ? and put the Sum in the first avaialble row in Column E ?

Comment: I sum the row E and put the sum in another cell for example in b

Comment: @Houyam have you tested the code and my answer below ? did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the code below will SUM all the values in Column E (starting from Cell E2), and will put the result in Cell B2. (you can modify the location easily)

**Note**: I've added "Option 2", instead of using a `For` loop, you can use the `WorksheetFunction.Sum` to sum all the values inside a Range without needing to iterate.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumColE()

Dim cumul As Long, I As Long, E As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    I = .Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row '<-- get last row in Column E        
    cumul = 0

    ' option 1: using a loop
    For E = 2 To I
        cumul = cumul + .Range("E" & E) '<-- Sum up values in Column E
    Next E
    .Range("B2").Value = cumul '<-- put the result in B2

    ' option 2: using WorksheetFunction SUM
    .Range("B2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("E2:E" & I))        
End With

End Sub
```